# Clock app "No Alarms" message on the background

Tags: iphone, clock

In iPhone Clock App, on Alarm tab, if there are no alarms or if the last alarm is deleted, a message is displayed on the background view "No Alarms".

How can that be implemented?

I am using a TableViewController to implement a list of data and want to show a similar "No Data" when the last row is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep memory of what alarms have been set, and when there aren't any set you just use viewWillAppear: to do the setup for whatever you want.

You'll have to somehow persist the memory between run-times, but that's outside the scope of your question.

As for the second half of it, you can either create a view over the table (using viewWillAppear:) to display the message, or just create a 'dummy' cell to tell the user that, depending on the desired effect.